# Equivalence of the Classical and Approximate Intermediate Value Theorems in Classical Logic

Tags: real-analysis, logic, solution-verification, constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic

**IVT** (Classical) Let $f:\left[a,b\right]\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous. If $f\left(a\right)<0$ and $f\left(b\right)>0$, then there exists $c\in\left(a,b\right)$ such that $f\left(c\right)=0$.

In intuitionistic logic, there's no proof of the classical form of the Intermediate Value Theorem. However, there is an approximate form which can be proved in intuitionistic logic.

**IVT** (Approximate) Let $f:\left[a,b\right]\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous. If $f\left(a\right)<0$ and $f\left(b\right)>0$, then, for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $c\in\left(a,b\right)$ such that $|f\left(c\right)|<\varepsilon$.

While IVT (Classical) and IVT (Approximate) are not equivalent in intuitionistic logic, they *are* in classical logic. Below is my attempt at a proof of this equivalence.

**Proposition.** IVT (Classical) is equivalent to IVT (Approximate) in classical logic.

**Proof.**

Let $f:\left[a,b\right]\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous such that $f\left(a\right)<0$ and $f\left(b\right)>0$.

For any $\varepsilon>0$, the classical form immediately determines a $c\in\left(a,b\right)$ such that $|f\left(c\right)|=0<\varepsilon$.

On the other hand, suppose that, for all $\varepsilon>0$, we have that there exists $x\in\left(a,b\right)$ such that $|f\left(x\right)|<\varepsilon$. Then, we may define a sequence $\left(c_{N}\right)_{N\geq1}$ such that $|f\left(c_{N}\right)|<1/N$. Then, $|f\left(c_{N}\right)|\to0$ as $N\to0$.

Since $\left(c_{N}\right)_{N\geq1}$ is bounded below and above by $a$ and $b$, respectively, there is a convergent subsequence (Bolzano-Weierstrass). Since we may evaluate $f$ along a convergent subsequence, we may, without loss in generality, assume $c_{N}\to c\in\left(a,b\right)$.

Therefore, $|f\left(c_{N}\right)|\to|f\left(c\right)|$, and so we have a $c\in\left(a,b\right)$ such that $f\left(c\right)=0$, as required.

**QED**

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Your proof looks absolutely fine to me.

Comment: @RobArthan Thank you!

Comment: Proof looks good to me too. However, it's actually possible to prove it without relying on any form of the axiom of choice to pick the sequence $c$.  This is because one can show that for all $\epsilon$, there exists rational $c \in (a, b)$ such that $|f(c)| < \epsilon$ (this follows because $\{c \in (a, b) | |f(c)| < \epsilon\}$ is open and inhabited, and $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense). The rational numbers, being in bijection with the naturals, can be well-ordered; from there, one can pick a sequence of rational numbers $c_n$ such that $c_n < 1/n$ using the well-order rather than countable choice.

Comment: @MarkSaving Thank you! Somehow the axiom of choice hadn't crossed my mind when I wrote this.